# Understanding docker port diversion

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am running following docker containers, and trying to understand that broker1 is diverting traffic from 0.0.0.0:9092 to 9092 tcp.

However, what I don't understand that why 9092/tcp is mentioned in broker2, and broker3.

Please can you explain what it mean and how it should be read?

```
3cd460e3fa52        cp-kafka:5.4.0            "/etc…"  **9092/tcp**, 0.0.0.0:9093->9093/tcp                     broker2

b4f98058eadf        cp-kafka:5.4.0            "/etc…"   **9092/tcp**, 0.0.0.0:9094->9094/tcp                       broker3

0886c9d90674        cp-kafka:5.4.0            "/etc…"   0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                            broker1
```

thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you're not exposing the port when you run the container, the [image itself](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/5.4.1-post/kafka/Dockerfile.ubi8#L51) is baked to expose it, per this line in the Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 9092
```

But if you don't configure your `KAFKA_LISTENERS` to use it, then whilst the port is exposed, nothing is listening on it. The [Dockerfile docs for `EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) explain this more.

So in short, this is just an aberration that you can ignore, assuming that your [listeners are functioning correctly](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/).

---

Here's an example against [this Docker Compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/mqtt-tracker/docker-compose.yml) with three brokers. Each has two listeners (internal and external), and exposes just the external one ([see here for why](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/)).

The relevant part of the yaml is this:

```yaml
  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:39092,HOST://0.0.0.0:9092
…
  kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0
    ports:
      - 19092:19092
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:49092,HOST://0.0.0.0:19092
…
  kafka-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:59092,HOST://0.0.0.0:29092
```

With it running, `docker ps` shows the `ports` exposed as defined, along with `9092` for `kafka-2` and `kafka-3`:

```
➜ docker ps|grep 9092
b227c8fbeec8  confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0 […]  9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:19092->19092/tcp kafka-2
ce1f8c575ed7  confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0 […]  9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:29092->29092/tcp kafka-3
f914a18d9757  confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0 […]  0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp             kafka-1
```

But if we test if the port is open on each container, we can see that it is only on `kafka-1` where we have specified it as one of the `KAFKA_LISTENERS`:

```
➜ docker exec -it kafka-1 nc -vz localhost 9092
localhost [127.0.0.1] 9092 (?) open

➜ docker exec -it kafka-2 nc -vz localhost 9092
localhost [127.0.0.1] 9092 (?) : Connection refused

➜ docker exec -it kafka-3 nc -vz localhost 9092
localhost [127.0.0.1] 9092 (?) : Connection refused
```